# What is the role of the buried-buffer-list frame parameter in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs, I've read the following code snippet in `simple.el`:

```
(frame-parameter frame 'buried-buffer-list)
```

What is the exact meaning of the `'buried-buffer-list` parameter? 
What it is used for?

Comment: Good question.  None of the current answers provides an answer to "what this is this frame-parameter `buried-buffer-list' used for?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of <kbd>M-x describe function RET frame-parameter</kbd> is:

> frame-parameter is a built-in
>   function.
>
> ```
> (frame-parameter FRAME PARAMETER)
> ```
>
> Return FRAME's value for parameter
>   PARAMETER. If FRAME is nil, describe
>   the currently selected frame.

Also, have a look in the Elisp info manual for the node called ["Frame/Frame Parameters"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Frame-Parameters).  There isn't a specific reference to 'buried-buffer-list that I could find.

You might be able to get the value of it by evaluating:

```
(cdr (frame-parameter FRAME 'buffer-list))
```

since a "buried buffer" is just a buffer that's been pushed to the back of the list of buffers for a particular frame.  See the documentation for [`bury-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#The-Buffer-List):

> bury-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.
>
> (bury-buffer &optional BUFFER-OR-NAME)
>
> Put BUFFER-OR-NAME at the end of the list of all buffers. There it is
>   the least likely candidate for `other-buffer' to return; thus, the
>   least likely buffer for C-x b to select by default.
>
> You can specify a buffer name as BUFFER-OR-NAME, or an actual buffer
>   object.  If BUFFER-OR-NAME is nil or omitted, bury the current buffer.
>   Also, if BUFFER-OR-NAME is nil or omitted, remove the current buffer
>   from the selected window if it is displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at http://www.update.uu.se/~ams/slask/emacs/src/frame.h returns:

```
List of buffers that were viewed, then buried in this frame.  The
most recently buried buffer is first.
```

So in theory you can use cdr to obtain the same list as Ben Collins said.

Comment: The real question is : "What is a buried frame" ?

Comment: A buffer that was sent to the end of the buffer list.